# MVC 4 @Scripts "does not exist"

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I have just created an ASP.NET MVC 4 project and used Visual Studio 2012 RC to create a Controller and Razor Views for `Index` and `Create` Actions.

When I came to run the application, and browsed to the `Create` view, the following error was shown:

> Compiler Error Message: CS0103: The name 'Scripts' does not exist in
>   the current context

The problem is the following code which was added automatically to the bottom of the View:

```
@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

Why does Scripts not exist?

I looked at the base Web Page class in Assembly System.Web.Mvc.dll, v4.0.0.0

I can see the following helper properties available:

- Ajax
- Html
- Url

But nothing named Scripts.

Any ideas?

**EDIT:**

My Web.config file looks like this (untouched from the one that Visual Studio created):

```
  <system.web.webPages.razor>
    <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web.webPages.razor>
```

**EDIT #2:**

People are blogging about using the `@Scripts` helper:

- [SCOTT HANSELMAN Blog](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/VisualStudio2012RCIsReleasedTheBigWebRollup.aspx)
- [Codebetter.com](http://codebetter.com/howarddierking/2012/06/04/web-optimization-in-visual-studio-2012-rc)

Yet having just installed Visual Studio 2012 RC onto a fresh Windows 8 install I am still unable to use `@Scripts` even though Visual Studio adds it to the generated View!

**Solutions are presented below.**

I am not sure how to close this, because in the end an update seemed to resolve the issue. I double checked I had performed a clean install, using a new project. But the same failing project I had made works fine now after various updates and no manual obvious intervention. Thanks for all of the thoughts but there was definitely an issue at the time ;)

Comment: already try add in Web.config?
`<system.web.webPages.razor>
 <pages pageBaseType="">
   <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
   <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
   <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
   etc...
 </pages>`

Comment: I have added the section from Web.config, but I haven't changed anything in that file.

Comment: You mean "My Views\Web.config" file not the app root web.config. At any rate, it's incorrect and missing  <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization"/>. Did you install VS12 Beta prior to RC? What win8 version?

Comment: @RickAndMSFT I did a clean Win8 installation from the Release Preview ISO, along with an install from the VS 2012 RC ISO, to make absolutely sure it wasn't a conflict of versions.

Comment: @RickAndMSFT My Views\Web.config would miss any Views in Areas

Answer (score 270, accepted):

The key here is to add

```
 <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization" />
```

to BOTH web.config files. My scenario was that I had System.Web.Optimization reference in both project and the main/root web.config but @Scripts still didn't work properly. You need to add the namespace reference to the Views web.config file to make it work.

**UPDATE:**

Since the release of MVC 4 System.Web.Optimization is now obsolete. If you're starting with a blank solution you will need to install the following nuget package:

```
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization
```

You will still need to reference System.Web.Optimization in your web.config files. For more information see this topic:

[How to add reference to System.Web.Optimization for MVC-3-converted-to-4 app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9475893/how-to-add-reference-to-system-web-optimization-for-mvc-3-converted-to-4-app)

As many pointed out, **restart of VS** could be required after the above steps to make this work.

Comment: You may also have to run `Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization` from a blank ASP.NET MVC4 template as it is not included by default.

Comment: @Portman Yes indeed if you started with a blank MVC project template you need to install Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization package.

Comment: It only needs to be added in the web.config in the Views folder for me.

Comment: Installing the package from NuGet only updated my ROOT web.config, I had to manually update /Views/web.config

Comment: This is indeed the solution.  However, I needed to restart visual studio for this to be recognized.

Comment: I had to add this to my Views/Web.config and then restart Visual Studio.

Answer (score 49):

`@Styles` and `@Scripts` are 2 new helpers provided by `System.Web.Optimization` library. As the name suggests, they bundle and minify CSS and JavaScript files or resources respectively.

Try including the namespace `System.Web.Optimization` either by `@using` directive or through `web.config`

<del>http://ofps.oreilly.com/titles/9781449320317/ch_ClientOptimization.html#BundlingAndMinification</del>

**UPDATE**

Microsoft has moved the bundling/minification to a separate package called `Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization`. You can download the assembly from [nuget](http://nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization).

This [post](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vs11trainingcourse_aspnetandvisualstudio_topic5.aspx) will be useful to you.

Comment: Adding System.Web.Optimization says "CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Optimization' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Web". There is no reference called System.Web.Optimization to add either.

Comment: The System.Web.Optimization namespace has been made obsolete since this was answered, try using the Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization instead.
See this question for more info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9475893/how-to-add-reference-to-system-web-optimization-for-mvc-3-converted-to-4-app

Comment: Clarification: The `System.Web.Optimization` namespace is NOT deprecated, the `System.Web.Optimization.dll` is.

Comment: Thanks! It is working for me when I got the trouble with the Layout of the different AREA.

Answer (score 47):

There was one small step missing from the above, which I found on another post.  After adding

```
<add namespace="System.Web.Optimization" />
```

to your `~/Views/web.config` namespaces, **close and re-open Visual Studio.**  This is what I had to do to get this working.

Comment: Same here, restart of VS worked but before that it still showed the error... ?

Comment: Closing VS was not necessary in my case but I had to close and re-open the .cshtml view I was using

Answer (score 31):

I am using areas, and have just come up against this issue, I just copied the namespaces from the root web.config to the areas web. config and it now works!!

```
    <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization" />        
    <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages" />
```

Answer (score 15):

I had the same problem and I used WinMerge to help me track this down. But as I researched it more, I found that Rick has the perfect [blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rickandy/archive/2012/06/12/asp-net-mvc-4-beta-to-mvc-rc-upgrade-instructions.aspx) for it.

Summary:

- Add `<add namespace="System.Web.Optimization"/>` to both web.config files
- Run `Install-Package -IncludePrerelease Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization`
- Update Bundling code
- Update Layout file
- The last step is to update 10 other libraries. I didn't and it worked fine. So looks like you can procrastinate this one (unless I already updated 1 or more of them). :)

Comment: Thanks for answering this Dan! (And pointing out my blog). His question implied he started with RC, but I think you're right. He just added a controller with RC to a Beta project.

Comment: It has been a couple of weeks and you both certainly have me second guessing myself. I certainly put VS 2012 onto my tablet which had never had anything but Metro Apps and saw it fail. I will try again in a VM.

Comment: This worked for me. Read the linked article for exact instructions on what you need to do.

Answer (score 11):

I had the same issue:

The System.Web.Optimization version I was using was outdated for MVC4 RC.

I updated my packages using the package manager in VS 2010.

In this [MSDN blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rickandy/archive/2012/06/12/asp-net-mvc-4-beta-to-mvc-rc-upgrade-instructions.aspx), Mr. Andy talks about how to update your MVC 4 Beta project to MVC 4 RC.  Updating my packages got the Scripts (particularly the web optimization one) to resolve for me:

To install the latest System.Web.Optimization package, use Package Manager Console (Tools -> Library Package Manager -> Package Manager Console) and run the below command:

```
Install-Package -IncludePrerelease Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization
```

Use the System.Web.Optimization file included in the package in your references.

To update other packages:
Tools menu -> Library Package Manager -> Manage NuGet Packages for Solution.

Answer (score 5):

Create a new MVC 4 RC internet application and run it. Navigate to Login which uses the same code

```
 @section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

What allows Login.cshtml to work is the the Views\Web.config file (not the app root version) contains

```
<namespaces>

    <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization"/>

  </namespaces>
```

Why is your Create view not working and Login is?

Comment: I wasn't using Login - that may well have been broken at the time.

Answer (score 5):

Import System.Web.Optimization on top of your razor view as follows:

```
@using System.Web.Optimization
```

Answer (score 3):

I ran into this problem, however while running the command:

```
Install-Package -IncludePrerelease Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization
```

I received the cryptic message (gotta love a great pun before the first cup of coffee):

> Install-Package : The specified cryptographic algorithm is not
>   supported on this platform.

I am running this on Windows XP SP3 (not by choice) and what I found was that I had to follow the instructions posted by the user *artsnob* on the [ASP.NET Forum](http://forums.asp.net/t/1807607.aspx/1)

- Please uninstall the Nuget and try re-installing it. If you are unable to do this, login as an Administrator.
- Go to Tools=> Extension Manager => Select "Nuget Package Manager" => UnInstall
- Install it again, by searching "Nuget" => Install.
- If it did not work, please try installing, 1.7.x version as I mentioned in the previous post (It doesn't mean, you have to use the previous version, if it works fine, we can report this bug, and get the patches for the latest version).

Once I ran this I could then run the command line to update the Web.Optimization.

Hope this saves someone some digging.

Answer (score 2):

Just write

```
@section Scripts{
    <script src="@System.Web.Optimization.BundleTable.Bundles.ResolveBundleUrl("~/bundles/jqueryval")"></script>
}
```

Comment: @archil Thanks for the replacement - that will be a good temporary solution. But the main question was "Why does Scripts not exist?"

Comment: @Jamie should it exist? I mean, as far as I remember, there is no Scipts helper out there. Maybe you are trying to use some third-party helper?

Comment: I didn't add that code myself - Visual Studio 2012 RC added it when it created the View for my Create Action. I think somehow my MVC 4 is not the right one. It must work somewhere because Scott Hanselman makes mention of the failing syntax as being a new addition to MVC 4 RC: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/VisualStudio2012RCIsReleasedTheBigWebRollup.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I upgraded from Beta to RC and faced 'Scripts' does not exist issue. Surfed all over the web and the final solution is what N40JPJ said plus another workaroudn:

Copy the following in View\Web.config :

```
  <namespaces>
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization"/>
    <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers"/>
  </namespaces>
```

and the following inside View\Shared_Layout.cshtml

```
@if (IsSectionDefined("scripts")) 
{
       @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: There is no need to use `if (IsSectionDefined())` unless you are providing an `else` clause. The fact that you are saying `required: false` already allows that section to not be defined, and in that case the section will be omitted. So this is unnecessary extra code.

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar error when upgrading a project from MVC3 to MVC4.

> Compiler Error Message: CS0103: The name [blah] does not exist in the
>   current context

In my case, I had outdated version numbers in several of my Web.Configs.

1. I needed to update the System.Web.Mvc version number from "3.0.0.0" to "4.0.0.0" in every Web.Config in my project.
2. I needed to update all of my System.Web.WebPages, System.Web.Helpers, and System.Web.Razor version numbers from "1.0.0.0" to "2.0.0.0" in every Web.Config in my project.

**Ex:**

```
<configSections>
  <sectionGroup name="system.web.webPages.razor" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorWebSectionGroup, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
    <section name="host" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.HostSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
    <section name="pages" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorPagesSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
  </sectionGroup>
</configSections>

...

<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
  <assemblies>
    <add assembly="System.Web.Helpers, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <add assembly="System.Web.WebPages, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
  </assemblies>
</compilation>
```

*Be sure to review the Web.Configs in each of your Views directories.*

You can read more about [Upgrading an ASP.NET MVC 3 Project to ASP.NET MVC 4](http://www.asp.net/whitepapers/mvc4-release-notes#_Toc303253806).

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you have created an 'Empty' project type without 'Scripts' folder.
My advice
-create a 'Basic' project type with full 'Scripts' folder.

With respect to all developers.

Answer (score 0):

just remove/ hide the code from create & Edit razor view of your controller.

```
 @section Scripts {  

   @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")  
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

1. : remove view page.
2. : add namespace webconfig (in view directory)
3. : create view an try!

good luck...

Answer (score 0):

One more for the pot - spent ages trying to work out the same problem - even though it was defined in the web.config for root and the root of Views.  Turns out I'd mistakenly added it to the `<system.web><pages><namespaces>`, and not `<system.web**.webPages.razor**><pages><namespaces>` element.

Really easy to miss that!

Answer (score 0):

When I enter on a page that haves this code:

```
@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

This error occurs: **Error. An error occurred while processing your request.**

And this exception are recorded on my logs:

```
System.Web.HttpException (0x80004005): The controller for path '/bundles/jqueryval' was not found or does not implement IController.
   em System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.GetControllerInstance(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType)
...
```

I have tried all tips on this page and none of them solved for me. So I have looked on my Packages folder and noticed that I have two versions for System.Web.Optmization.dll:

- Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization.1.1.0 **(v1.1.30515.0 - 68,7KB)**
- Microsoft.Web.Optimization.1.0.0-beta
  **(v1.0.0.0 - 304KB)**

My project was referencing to the older beta version. I only changed the reference to the newer version (69KB) and eveything worked fine.

I think it might help someone.

Answer (score 0):

That has an obvious solution. I had the same problem later. Not related to Assembly References or ... .It'll occur In hierarchy calling of MVC Partial views, when you have complicated page structures. So calling/rendering each part separately on each page (maybe a master page or partial) will cause to not see required parts of page like the bellow code :

```
@RenderSection("Scripts", required: false)
```

That simply forces page to find and render related section and in case of failure shows you an error message like you.

So I suggest you to trace your pages (like program trace) from master to all of its partials to **Detect Dependencies**. Maybe it be a terrible work, but no other choices available here.

**Not that according to my experience, some conditional situations in programming causes not to show you the right error causes the problem.**

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue after I added an Area to a project that didn't have any.
To get rid of it just copied the web.config withing root Views folder to the Views folder of the area and it started working.

Answer (score 0):

I solve this problem in MvcMusicStore by add this part of code in _Layout.cshtml

```
@if (IsSectionDefined("scripts")) 
{
       @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
}
```

and remove this code from Edit.cshtml

```
 @section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For me this solved the problem, in NuGet package manager console write following:

```
update-package microsoft.aspnet.mvc -reinstall
```

Answer (score 0):

When i started using MVC4 recently i faced the above issue while creating a project with the empty templates.
Steps to fix the issue.

1. Goto `TOOLS` --> `Library Package Manager` --> `Packager Manager Console`
   Paste the below command and press enter
   `Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization`
   Note: wait for successful installation.
2. Goto Web.Config file in root level and add below namespace in pages namespace section.
   add `<namespace="System.Web.Optimization" />`
3. Goto Web.Config in Views folder and follow the step 2.
4. Build the solution and run.

The Package mentioned in step 1 will add few system libraries into the solution references like System.Web.Optimization is not a default reference for empty templates in MVC4.

I hope this helps.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you added   to your web.config and it still shows message, then you need to close your project and reopen it, now it will exist and @Styles.Render("") and @Scripts.Render() will work fine.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
@section Scripts 
{
    Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")  // <- without ampersand at the begin
}
```