# After installing AspNet5RC1, can no longer open cshtml files in any previous / new MVC project

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

After installing AspNet5.ENU.RC1 any previous or new MVC project throws a

> The operation could not be completed. Invalid pointer

error when opening razor pages (`.cshtml`). Other files such as class libraries and config files open as expected. Any suggestions before I reinstall VS?

Comment: try open the folder: Users\<CurrentUser>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\<version>\ 
delete the folder: ComponentModelCache 
restart Visual Studio.

Comment: I still had error after deleting ComponentModelCache folder and restarting VS; however, I deleted the whole parent <version> folder (14.0) and after restarting VS, it started behaving again :)  Thank You for taking me down this path.  I have another work computer that is behaving this way after performing the RC1 upgrade. I feel better that I don't have to reinstall!!

Comment: @chsword: Thanks for that!  I was running into the same problem.

Comment: thanks i wasted now an hour on this will try it

Comment: AND YES!!!! ow yeh!! worked. thanks a mi

Comment: Had this problem in Visual Studio 2015 and it worked. Thanks :)

Comment: Yes! Saved my morning! :)

Comment: @chsword Men you're awesome!

Answer (score 36):

As @chsword commented above:

1. Open the folder: Users\(user)\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio (version)
2. Delete the folder: ComponentModelCache
3. Restart Visual Studio (ComponentModelCache is re-created and the problem goes away)

Comment: One day headache then desperately try everything from the web and finally this.

Comment: Same here after 6 hours reinstalling Visual Studio doesn't work, later try this and that is all. Thansk

Comment: You are awesome. Thanks!

Comment: for VS2015 you can just cut and paste this into `Start > Run` : %localappdata%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\ and you'll see the folder right away

Comment: This required 2 restarts for me.  After removing that folder and restarting, I get the error: The 'CctProjectPackage' package did not load correctly.'  But I can now open csvhtml files.  After the second restart, it seems fine.  VS2015 Update 3