# Cannot have access to @Styles and @Scripts Helper in MVC

Tags: c#, razor, helper, bundling-and-minification

I cannot get access to The helper `@Styles` nor `@Scripts`. I have added `<add namespace="System.Web.Optimization" />` as proposed [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14799765/3229805) and [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23534633/3229805). I use to have this problem, but i solved it by adding `@using System.Web.Optimisation`

Here are my configs (the relevant part):

```
 <system.web.webPages.razor>
<host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
<pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
  <namespaces>
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Optimisation" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
    <add namespace="CariSSC" />
  </namespaces>
</pages>
```

I read a couple of blogs online and they all point to the same solution. Any clues on how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You misspelled Optimization namespace in your config file. You have Optimisation when it should be Optimization.

Comment: I'm a quebecer and i speak french. Probably why it didn't jumped out! Thanks a lot!