# @Scripts doesn't exist in Asp.Net MVC

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor, model-validation

I'm trying to add Model validation in Asp.Net MVC , 
So I need to import the libraries at first inside **Views\Share_Layout.cshtml** .

Then it kills me in a second.

**@Scripts doesn't exist**

[image: @Scripts doesn't exist]

What is going on ?
If some further information needed , please tell me. Thanks :)

Comment: Keep your scripts inside this @section scripts{ }

Comment: Possible duplicate: [MVC 4 @Scripts “does not exist”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10951669/mvc-4-scripts-does-not-exist)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Install `Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization`
2. In `web.config` (Views folder) make sure you have under namespaces `<add namespace="System.Web.Optimization"/>`