# Nuget command always pending and doesn't work

Tags: visual-studio-2015, nuget

It works fine before ... 
But today I'm working with ASP.Net MVC. 
I am going to install ASP.NET Web Optimization... 1.1.3 
using Nuget command or to find solutions.

And it seems always pending without any response.

What is going on here ?

[image]

This is what in my Nuget.config ..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <packageSources>
    <add key="nuget.org" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" protocolVersion="3" />
  </packageSources>
  <disabledPackageSources>
    <add key="Microsoft and .NET" value="true" />
  </disabledPackageSources>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Does this issue only occurred on the ASP.Net MVC project? How about the C# class library project? According to the attachment image, I noticed that always loading on the updates tab, is this your question? could you get any package on the Browse tab? Besides, The package Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization is installed automatically with the template, no need to install it again, why you going to install it?

Comment: Not only in Asp.Net MVC project but also a small c# console application can't run Nuget .., Browse and other tags can't work , too , As well as it doesn't work on each command I type in the PM Console . Due to  this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43159078/scripts-doesnt-exist-in-asp-net-mvc, I can't find @Scripts  so I need to import Web Optimization :<

Comment: thanks for you reply. what is your package sources? Is https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json and could you open this link in the browser? Then check whether is your machine behind a proxy or firewall or have set any proxy in the environment? If not, try to uninstall the nuget package manager and delete the NuGet.config from %appdata%\nuget, restart VS, install it again, check if it works.

Comment: Yes , is api.nuget.org/v3/index.json  and I have deleted the NuGet config but still not works. So the problem seems relating to the proxy , but I'm not familiar with it . I am busy lately , really thanks in advance :) !!! I have checked the system environment ,  there is no http_proxy . Is there any other  information I can give you ?

Comment: strange. Could you open the link https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json in the browser directly? And try to use nuget command line to install a package in Package Manager Console, like: Install-Package Newtonsoft.Json and check the result. If it does not work, please share us the error messages. If all above not help you, try to uninstall NuGet Package Manager and reinstall.

Comment: Oops ! Na , I can't open the link ! What happens to it ?  And the resource Newtonsoft.Json can't be found when I using PM command.

Comment: That is because your network is limited, try to access that link with VPN.

Comment: Is this the point why my NuGet can't work?  I'm not familiar with VPN…Could you give me some directions what to do ?

Comment: Nuget worked fine before, just suddenly became out of control…

Comment: If you work in the company, I suggest you contact your IT and ask for help. If you still want to know how to unlock network restrictions, you can open a new post which is benefit to other communities give a better solution. Thanks.

Comment: I am working on my own .. haha :( , but guess what ? Nuget miraculously works again , I didn't do anything ... it seems a known recent issue ?? ... I am so confused now , real thanks for u.