# Is System.Web.Optimization part of .Net Framework 4.5?

Tags: asp.net, .net, .net-4.5

I've been using [`Microsoft.Web.Optimization`](http://nuget.org/packages/microsoft.web.optimization) package for some time via the Visual Studio 2012 *trial*.  I was thinking that the Optimization Namespace would be part of .NET 4.5 as [stated here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.optimization%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

However, I installed the new release of [Visual Studio 2012 & .NET Framework 4.5](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/11/en-us/downloads), and now there's no `System.Web.Optimization` namespace by default! I had to install the package through [NuGet](http://nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization)

Is the VS 2012 Ultimate release not yet complete?  Or, is the `Microsoft.Web.Optimization` namespace not in .NET 4.5?

Comment: Technically, this is Too Localized, as .NET 4.5 has been released.  Questions about trial software that has been released are Too Localized.

Comment: What do you mean? Is VS 2012 trial not yet complete?

Comment: The new version of VS was released about two weeks ago.

Comment: Yes, that's what I've got, so technically System.Web.Optimization is not part of Asp.Net 4.5!

Comment: I would say no.  It's a separate package you get through NuGet.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Microsoft is adopting a new strategy with VS2012 in which they are componentizing more of the new features as packages that can be downloaded via nuget.  For example, Entity Framework, MVC4, WebApi, Web Optimization, etc.. are all now packages rather than part of the framework.

The reason is that these systems can now be easily upgraded out of cycle with the rest of the framework.  Thus, MVC5 can be easily released without waiting for .NET 5, and Web Optimization v2 can be released whenever it might be ready.

Comment: Thanks, all makes perfect sense now

Answer (score 15):

Here is a similar question:

- [How to add reference to System.Web.Optimization for MVC-3-converted-to-4 app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9475893/how-to-add-reference-to-system-web-optimization-for-mvc-3-converted-to-4-app)

`Microsoft.Web.Optimization` package is now "legacy":

- [Microsoft.Web.Optimization 1.0.0-beta2](http://nuget.org/packages/microsoft.web.optimization)

The new package is `Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization`:

- [Microsoft ASP.NET Web Optimization Framework 1.0.0](http://nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization)

*`Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization` and `Microsoft.Web.Optimization` are NOT part of .NET Framework 4.5.*

- [.NET Framework 4.5 Class Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg145045)