# Minification JS file on each and every *.cshtml page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs, bundling-and-minification

The app I'm working on has been developed by using ASP.net MVC and AngularJs. It's not a SPA app.I need to do bundling and minification of my JS files.I know how to do it on "Layout page".For that I have used this [Bundling and Minification](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/performance/bundling-and-minification) tutorial.

But **My question** is how can I Minification my JS file on each and every *.cshtml page ? And I need that JS file as unminified when I do the debug.Can I achieve that ?  Any help would be highly appreciated.

Here is my "index.cshtml" page with JS file resides on bottom of the page.I would like to do Minification this js file.

```
//removed html code for clarity
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Resources/js/controllers/MyTestController.js"> </script>
```

Comment: The tutorial shows you how to create a `ScriptBundle` and include it on a page. What part don't you understand? (and if you want it on every page, why not just put in the layout page so you only need to include it once)

Comment: @StephenMuecke No.When I put those angular controller JS files on layout page ,it doesn't work.Need to load those files on each and every *.cshtml page.Otherwise It won't bind the controller.I have put all other common js on layout page and works fine.The problem is how to do minification on page level js files ?

Comment: Its no different. Just create a new `ScriptBundle` that includes that file, then add `@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/yourFile")` in the pages

Comment: @StephenMuecke Thanks for suggestion.Can you put that as an answer ? Then I can close this thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a new `ScriptBundle` in `BundleConfig.cs`

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/yourFile").Include(
  "..." // your file(s)
));
```

and in you view

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/yourFile")
```

Answer (score 0):

1.Use Nuget to install the package: Install-Package     `Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization`
2.Create a BundleConfig Class and define your bundles:

```
using System.Web.Optimization;
public class BundleConfig
{
    public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
    {
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/js").Include(
                  "~/Scripts/*.js"));
        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/bundles/css").Include(
                   "~/Styles/*.css")); 
    } 
}
```

3.Register the **BundleConfig** class within the **application start** in the **global.asax**

```
void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
}
```

4.reference the bundles in your HTML document.
5.Enable bundling by disabling debug mode.
reference source: [Bundling and minification without ASP.NET MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22345420/bundling-and-minification-without-asp-net-mvc)