# The type or namespace name 'ScriptBundle' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Tags: model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-4

```
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Optimization;

bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryui").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-ui-{version}.js"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive*",
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));
```

I am getting the error:

```
Error   16  The type or namespace name 'ScriptBundle' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Looks like some reference issue, but i am not able to figure it out. Please help. What could be causing this error?

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9475893/how-to-add-reference-to-system-web-optimization-for-mvc-3-converted-to-4-app) may give a hint, you need to reference `System.Web.Optimization.dll`.

Comment: Thanks Joachim, but it already has that reference using System.Web.Optimization. May be looks like i will have to uninstall the reference and it back again.

Comment: I had the similar issue <strong>[This][1]</strong> resolved it.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9475893/how-to-add-reference-to-system-web-optimization-for-mvc-3-converted-to-4-app

Answer (score 13):

```
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization
```

Answer (score 1):

I got this error when I was upgrading an MVC3 project to MVC4. I was missing the reference to System.Web.Optimization.dll which is in the NuGet package Microsoft ASP.NET Web Optimization Framework (Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. here is the solution
 **[How to add reference to System.Web.Optimization for MVC-3-converted-to-4 app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9475893/how-to-add-reference-to-system-web-optimization-for-mvc-3-converted-to-4-app)**.