# Why js file not loading when full url is entered in asp.net mvc?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, web-config, static-content

I'm trying to load a js file in my mvc view. When I enter the full URL in the browser, the page can't load the js file but if I skip the view name in the URL it can. Please have a look at the following images for clarification:

[image]

[image]

I'm trying to load my js file like below:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Resources/dynamsoft.webtwain.initiate.js"></script>
```

What can be the reason? Thanks.

Comment: Is Index a default action defined in your route dict?

Comment: looks like the view is not a part of the file path

Comment: Can you please explain a little more? @talsibony

Comment: show mark up that loads js

Comment: Edited my question, please have a look. I have my js file Resources folder, which is a root folder to my project. @Imad

Comment: It looks like you're using a relative file path to reference the file, rather than an absolute one. When at `home/index` it looks for it in the "home" folder that doesn't exist. You need to change your view and/or master page where it is including the script file.

Comment: For example, remove the tilde. That's not valid.

Comment: I am not sure how you do it in asp, but usually when I am starting a project in php, I defined a variable that contains the absolute url path to the js resources, then I use it every place I want to include js file, so it looks like: jsPath + 'filname.js' this way I know that the file will be included no matter what is the current url of the web application

Comment: Change your declaration as `<script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~")/Resources/dynamsoft.webtwain.initiate.js"></script>`

Comment: can you add your RouteConfig.cs code under App_Start

Answer (score -1):

In first screen the site unable to get the js file path .
Better to use bundleconfig.cs to bind all js and css files.

click [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21668280/how-do-i-add-bundleconfig-cs-to-my-project) to know how to use bundleconfig in MVC