# MVC Styles and Scripts do not exist in the current context

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

As a learning exercise, I've created a blank MVC4 Application and I'm building a blog-type website with it.

I'm learning that this probably wasn't the best idea... I've copied the `Content` and `Views\Shared` folders into my blog project from another one I created with the default stuff, but the following lines are giving me errors:

```
@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
```

Both underlined red in my _Layout.cshtml file, the error is:

> The name  does not exist in the current context

So I went back to my "default" project and checked where those come from by hovering over them. The tooltip said

```
class System.Web.Optimization.Styles
class System.Web.Optimization.Scripts
```

So I went through and installed the Web Optimization Framework as per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9475893/how-to-add-reference-to-system-web-optimization-for-mvc-3-converted-to-4-app) but it hasn't fixed the problem.

The project builds n all, but no styles are applied and I'm 100% sure anything that the script controls isn't working either...

Can anyone help me fix this?

Comment: Make sure you've defined those bundles in BundleConfig.cs file like bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include("~/Content/site.css"));

Comment: Make sure you include `<add namespace="System.Web.Optimization"/>` in your Views folder `web.config` file as well. Might need to close and open your solution again for Visual Studio's intellisense to pick it up though.

Comment: @malkam thanks! Had to change the namespace there for it to work, but I also had to reload the solution as `Dom` suggested

Comment: @malkam I got that sorted as per my last comment, but now the <link /> is being rendered as `<link href="/Content/css" rel="stylesheet"/>` ... I've checked it against an unmodified "Internet Application" template and everything I can see looks exactly the same

Comment: Turns out I needed to register the Bundle in the Global.asax file

Answer (score 2):

add `<add namespace="System.Web.Optimization" />` tag into your **web.config** that is inside of **Views** folder

like this :

```
>  <system.web.webPages.razor>
>     <host factoryType= ... />
>     <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
>       <namespaces>
>         <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
>         <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
>         <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
>         <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
>         <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization" /> 
>       </namespaces>
>     </pages>   
>  </system.web.webPages.razor>
```

Comment: I already have that namespace in my web.config folder but still I am getting the same error