# How to add scripts from .ascx to .aspx <HEAD> section

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, ascx, bundles

I want to use:

```
<%:  System.Web.Optimization.Scripts.Render("~/bundles/MyBundle") %>
```

in .ascx file. There is no problem when i am loading scripts to body. However, i don't know, how to include this script to <**head**> of my .aspx file. Any ideas? I cannot do this from code behind.

Answer (score 1):

`<head>
<script src=<%= Page.ResolveClientUrl(~/bundles/MyBundle") %> type=text/javascript></script>
</head>`
You can use this to include in your .aspx page

Comment: It is not the case...System.Web.Optimization.Scripts.Render dose this by default. I know how to include my bundle to aspx from ascx, but i want to do it directly to head

Comment: Am I missing something? This is in the header block?

Comment: Yes its in the header block

Comment: @HamzaHaider Yes exactly, isn't this what op has asked for? If this is not his solution then it's not very clear what he's after

Comment: I mean that i want to include it to head tag FROM ASCX. I cannot have another head tag i ascx file. It is clearly said in title "add scripts form ascx to aspx <head> section" I cant include them directly to aspx

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft.Web.Optimization is now obsolute. With MVC 4, you can use Microsoft Asp.Net web optimization framework.

You can install It from a [NuGet package:](https://www.nuget.org/packages/microsoft.aspnet.web.optimization)

After installation, configure bundle(s) in App_Start\BundleConfig.cs:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/Scripts/jquery").Include(
            "~/Scripts/Lib/jquery/jquery-{version}.js",
        "~/Scripts/Lib/jquery/jquery.*",
        "~/Scripts/Lib/jquery/jquery-ui-{version}.js")
    );
```

More information on how to configure and use it here:

[How to add reference to System.Web.Optimization for MVC-3-converted-to-4 app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9475893/how-to-add-reference-to-system-web-optimization-for-mvc-3-converted-to-4-app)

Comment: This is not what i have asked for. I have my bundleconfig file created and configured. I only need to know how to put those bundles to head section.